# I need to convert to POS

Tags: logic

> Convert $AB+ACB+DC'A$ to POS.

\begin{align} AB+ACB+DC'A 
&= AB(1+C)+DC'A\\
&= AB+DC'A' \\
&= A(B+DC') \\
&=A(B+D)(B+C')
\end{align}

Can someone tell me if I did this correct?

Comment: I originally confused (what I now believe was) a numbered sequence of steps for answer-choices, like to a multiple choice question.

Comment: What is POS? Which system are you working with?

Comment: Factor the expression to obtain a product of sums.

Comment: Its Boolean Algebra.

Comment: Looks good except for that typographical dash that appears after the last A in the second line but fortunately disappears in the third line.

Comment: Answer converted to comment, from longoria: "Thanks to everyone for your support. I have an exam Monday and have been studying all day. I have made excellent progress."

Comment: @GrahamKemp: the dashes indicate negation (see my answer).

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, but there shouldn't be one after that second A in the second line.

Answer (score 1):

These days it is more common to use logic notation rather than arithmetic notation for the operators in Boolean algebra: so I'd write your $AB + ACB + DC'A$ as $(A \land B) \lor (A \land C \land B) \lor (D \land \lnot C \land A)$. And then your "product of sums" is a [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form). To me the modern notation makes something like the equivalence:

$$
B \lor (D \land \lnot C) \equiv (B \lor D) \land (B \land \lnot C)
$$

that you use in your last step much more natural.
However, if the arithmetic notation is what you want to use, your solution is fine.